# PHP mysqli search multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I'm trying to search through 3 different tables however it doesn't seem to be working. I have to remove username from the users table and then it works. How can I search different columns in each table?

```
$query = "(SELECT name, 'talent' FROM talent WHERE name LIKE '%" . $q ."%') 
           UNION ALL
           (SELECT name, username, 'users' FROM users WHERE name LIKE '%" . $q ."%') 
           UNION ALL
           (SELECT name, 'venues' FROM venues WHERE name LIKE '%" . $q ."%')";
```

Comment: Every `UNION`ed subquery must return exactly the same number of columns. Every corresponding column must be of compatible type as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first and last UNION are returning 2 columns

The middle UNION is returning 3 columns , so removing username didn't give error

Number of columns and type of columns should be same while using UNION

Comment: how could i do it if they don't have the same number columns and type of columns?

Comment: @user2570937, you need to give empty value or NULL value if column doesn't have value in one of the select